# How to restore files from a deleted user?

Tags: 20.04, restore

I tried the kde plasma environment but it crashed and I removed a user. When I removed him I pressed the "keep files" but I can't find the files anywhere. Where are those files? I searched the username in my disk but I found nothing, not even a locked file or something like that. What can I do?
(Note:I am using ubuntu 20.04, focal fossa)

Comment: Please open a terminal and enter the following command: `ls /home -l`. Then copy and paste the output of the command [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1317714/edit). Then format the pasted output as `code` using the { } icon above the edit question window. Finally indicate in your question if you see the user name in the pasted output.

Comment: I cannot see the username in the list.

Comment: Then its gone! :(